# Unexplained NullReferenceException thrown while exporting data

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, datagrid, nullreferenceexception

When I try to export data from datagrid in the application, it only exports 15 rows (+ the header) and then on the 16th row it throws `NullReferenceException`. A couple times it managed to export 35 rows and then throw the exception on the 36th row, but most of the time it stops at 15. Has anyone encountered this type of problem? Why does the 16th row cause this issue?

I am building a C# WPF application where the user can read data from the database to a datagrdid view on a click of a button. I made another button to export the data from the datagrid to an Excel file, in case the user needs the data in Excel. Because I assume it has something to do with the memory I tried rebooting the PC to see how many rows it can export, and then usually (not always) it exports to the 35th row, and than on the second time I hit run it exports only to the 15th row. The table is fairly large (182 columns), so I tried with a smaller table with only 2 columns and 40 rows, and there is no change in the behavior. This is the function that handles the `on_click` event for the export button.

> ```
> private void ExportToExcel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
> {
>     Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
>     excel.Visible = true;
>     Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
>     Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
>
>     for (int j = 0; j < DelavciDataGrid.Columns.Count; j++)
>     {
>         Range myRange = (Range)sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1];
>         sheet1.Cells[1, j + 1].Font.Bold = true;
>         myRange.Value2 = DelavciDataGrid.Columns[j].Header;
>     }
>
>     for (int i = 1; i < DelavciDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
>     {
>         for (int j = 0; j < DelavciDataGrid.Columns.Count; j++)
>         {
>             Range myRangee = (Range)sheet1.Cells[i + 1, j + 1];
>             TextBlock b = DelavciDataGrid.Columns[j].GetCellContent(DelavciDataGrid.Items[i - 1]) as TextBlock;
>             myRangee.Value2 = b.Text;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

On the click of the export button Excel is opened and it fills the headers from the datagrid to the spreadsheet, and then the rows and the columns starting 1 row 1 column, and that is OK. But then it gets to row 16 and it throws `NullReferenceException` on line

```
myRangee.Value2 = b.Text;
```

I tried using the debugger and indeed, `b.Text` is set to null on the 16th row, but that is what confuses me. There is a value in the 16th row and as I said I managed to export couple of times to the 35th row from the same table with the same query.

Answer (score -1):

My first thought if you are seeing null values but the value in that row isn't null is if your "as" cast is finding something it cannot convert into a textblock and returning null instead.  Maybe see what happens if you make an "preb" variable that is of type object and a "B" variable that is cast from preb, and see if A isn't null and B is null.  If that's the case then you may need to either cast to a different object or have an "if (b is X)" check to account for the problem.

Comment: I solved the problem, by exporting from the DataTable, instead the DataGridView.